# Connect C with MongoDB

Tags: c, mongodb

I need to connect MongoDB(database) with C language. I searched for it but I could not understand them. I am using c in netbeans. Is there any driver to connect or header files to be included. If it is then how can we do this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an open source libary for MongoDB in C language, you can check it on [GitHub](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver)